# Bad Performance on UICollectionView Scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView used to display images which I load from the filesystem. However, the scrolling appears to have a very bad performance, when scrolling up and down it is a bit shaky and not smoothly like it should - compared to the photo app from Apple.

In Detail: 
The user can select or take a photo with the camera which will then be saved to the file system in full res. The file url is then save in a core data database.

While performing a segue I come to the overview page where I have the collection view. Here I load the image through through the NSURL saved in the database, on loading I resize the image - from approx 900 kb down to 45 kb. This is working fine, so the image in the collection view is less than 50 kb which in my opinion isn't too much, right?

Here is the code:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let width = 90
    let height = 90
    let theSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    return theSize
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let myImageCell:ImageCell = myCollectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("imageCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as ImageCell

    var baseString:String = documentsDirectory()
    var pathComponents = [baseString, self.pictures[indexPath.row]]
    var theImageFile = NSURL.fileURLWithPathComponents(pathComponents)

    let theNewImage = self.scaleNewImage(theImageFile)// self.scaleNewImage(readImageFileFromDirectoryNSURL(self.pictures[0]))
    myImageCell.imageCell.image = theNewImage

    return myImageCell
}
```

// Here is the code to resize the image

```
func scaleNewImage (url:NSURL) -> UIImage {
        let src = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(url, nil)
        let scale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
        let value = (90) * scale // self.view.bounds.width/2
        let parameters = [
            kCGImageSourceShouldAllowFloat as String : true,
            kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform as String : true,
            kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageAlways as String : true,
            kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize as String : value
        ]
        let imageRef = CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(src, 0, parameters)
        let image = UIImage(CGImage: imageRef, scale: scale, orientation: .Up)!

        //println(image)
        //println(image.size)

        return image
    }
```

It would be great if someone can help, thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked into image caching?

Comment: No I haven't, would that help? I am quite new to swift/ iOS, how could this be achieved? Any examples? - No need for a solution, just the direction, thanks

Comment: Directions are to google or the search box at the top of the page :-)

Comment: I could say "not thank you" I already looked for but if you never did anything with caching it is not easy to find a start, I thought Stackoverflow is here to provide a help from dev to dev...as I already did.... never mind, please in future questions from me, just ignore me, thanks!

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+ios+image+cache

Comment: That is the search I already did... but thanks anyway, so far this only gives me solutions when I download an image, but I keep on searching...

Comment: The cache is basically the same once you have the image, it doesn't matter if the image comes from disk (and is then modified in your case) or from the web.

Comment: Ok, I think I will get it done, thanks for the direction ;-)

Comment: Performance problem occurs because you scale image every time cellForItemAtIndexPath is called (and that is really often). You need to scale images before loading collectionView and load scaled image from disk/memory.

Comment: Thanks Ivo, you are right, now the scrolling is very smoothly. You helped me a lot...

Comment: it is because your image not cache. Use Haneke :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Haneke

```
var theImageFile = NSURL.fileURLWithPathComponents(pathComponents)
imageCell.hnk_setImageFromURL(theImageFile!)
```

Reference: http://blog.revivalx.com/2015/02/24/uicollectionview-tutorial-in-swift-using-alamofire-haneke-and-swiftyjson/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Dato but I solved the issue with the solution from Ivo. Just needed some more adjustments on threading and now everything works fast and smoothly. But I might try your solution too...